# Subsequences- $a_{n}$ converges to -1 and 2: prove that $b_{n}=\frac{2{a_{n}^{2}-a_{n}-1}}{a_{n}^{2}+1}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I answerd a question but I feel like there's something missingor wrong.

The question:

Let $a_{n}$ be a sequence with only two partial limits: -1,2.

Let's define a new sequence $b_{n}$:

$$b_{n}=\frac{2{a_{n}^{2}-a_{n}-1}}{a_{n}^{2}+1}$$.

I need to prove that $b_{n}$ is convergent and to find it's limit.

I think that I should prove that $b_{n}$ is convergent by showing that there is no partial limit other than 1.

so, we can choose $b_{n_{k}}$ that converges to b, so $a_{n_{k}}$ can have only -1 or 2 as a limit, so we can choose $a_{n_{k_{j}}}$ to be convergent subsequence of $a_{n_{k}}$, and to find out no matter what is the limit that $b_{n_{k_{j}}}$ converges to 1, so $b_{n_{k}}$ as well.

Ok, so what's worng? :-)

Thank you.

Comment: 1.What's the definition of partial limit (being used here)?

Comment: I suppose that infinity is a possible partial limit with your definition. In that case it is true that a sequence is convergent if and only if there is only one possible partial limit. If you have shown that before in your course I would say your proof is fine. Otherwise you need to include an argument showing this.

Comment: Yeah, partial limit is s subsequential limit.

Comment: I don't need to consider  infinity as a possible partial limit in this case.

Comment: What is the definition of partial or sub sequential limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose that you first prove (from your favourite definition of "partial limit") that the sequence $a_n$ can be split into two convergent sequences without overlap or rest.

The proof for $b_n$ will then be much simpler to write down.